# Display list of different data types created from user input in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm trying to create a program that will take in student information from the user and display it on the console. The user is able to choose if they'd like to enter information or display information from a menu. I think I have the list set up to take in the student information, but my lists aren't displaying, can someone give me any suggestions?

Here's my list code:

```
  public static List<undergradList> addUnderGrad(List<undergradList> list)
    {
        bool done;
        List<undergradList> listB = new List<undergradList>();
        undergradList ugl = new undergradList();

        Console.WriteLine();
        do
        {
            done = false;
            try
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID.");
                    long userInput1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    ugl.studID = userInput1;

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name.");
                    string userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ugl.studName = userInput2;

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student DOB. (MM/DD/YY) ");
                    DateTime userInput3 = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    ugl.dateOfBirth = userInput3;

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Major.");
                    string userInput4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ugl.major = userInput4;

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Previous High School.");
                    string userInput5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ugl.previousHS = userInput5;

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Classification.");
                    string userInput6 = (Console.ReadLine());
                    ugl.stdClass = userInput6;

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Are you done entering students? (y/n)");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer == "y")
                {
                    done = true;
                }
                else { Console.WriteLine(); }
            }
            catch { Console.WriteLine("Answer invalid, try again."); }
        } while (done == false);
        return list;

    }
```

Here's my display code:

```
public static void showUndergradList(List<undergradList> listB)
    {
      foreach(var instance in listB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you use your debugger, is listB filled? Can you show how you call this two functions? Create a [mcve] also

Answer (score 1):

There are two issue in your code.

1. You need to use `listB.Add` method add an instance in the `List` when you fill your `undergradList` data otherwise, `listB` collection will not fill any data.
2. let `undergradList ugl = new undergradList();`  in loop otherwise, you will add the same instance in the `listB` collection.

code might look like this.

```
bool done;
List<undergradList> listB = new List<undergradList>();

Console.WriteLine();
do
{
    undergradList ugl = new undergradList(); //create a new instance in loop
    done = false;
    try
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID.");
            long userInput1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ugl.studID = userInput1;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name.");
            string userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
            ugl.studName = userInput2;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student DOB. (MM/DD/YY) ");
            DateTime userInput3 = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ugl.dateOfBirth = userInput3;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Major.");
            string userInput4 = Console.ReadLine();
            ugl.major = userInput4;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Previous High School.");
            string userInput5 = Console.ReadLine();
            ugl.previousHS = userInput5;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Classification.");
            string userInput6 = (Console.ReadLine());
            ugl.stdClass = userInput6;

        Console.WriteLine();


        listB.Add(ugl); //add instance in List


        Console.WriteLine("Are you done entering students? (y/n)");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "y")
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine(); }
    }
    catch { Console.WriteLine("Answer invalid, try again."); }
} while (done == false);
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable for list at Add method returns null because variable declared inside Add method.

```
  List<undergradList> listB = new List<undergradList>();
 public static List<undergradList> addUnderGrad(List<undergradList> list)
{
    undergradList ugl = new undergradList();
    bool done;

     //..
}
```

so declare List outside of any methods.